# convert object that holds a double to a string and then back to double

Tags: java

I have a two Dimensional Object array **(Object[][] data)** that holds pairs of products-prices.
I try to pass these values to a Map with the following way.

```
private String myPairs = "";
private String[] l, m;

for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    myPairs += (String)data[i][0] + ":" + String.valueOf(data[i][1]) + ",";
}

Map<String, Double> pairs = new java.util.HashMap<>();
l = myPairs.split(",");

for (int i=0; i<l.length; i++){
    m = l[i].split(":");
    pairs.put((String)m[0], Double.parseDouble((String)m[1]));             
}
```

I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. What's the wrong I have done?

Comment: on what line are you getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` ?, also go thru your debugger and you could solve it yourself .. :)

Comment: on line pairs.put((String)m[0], ....)

Comment: what contains in object data???

Comment: Why don't you directly add the values in the map in the first for loop? Or is the serialized representation used anywhere else you didn't provide?

Comment: Are you sure that the l array contains values and is correctly split?

Comment: Because myPairs variable is transferred as a String argument in a function  where the Mapping process is done.

Comment: Are the conversions I have made correct?

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or are you actually using this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for (int i=0; i<l.length-1; i++){
    m = l[i].split(":");
    pairs.put((String)m[0], Double.parseDouble((String)m[1]));             
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some explanation (otherwise people may misunderstand / not understand (and possibly down-vote, as happened here)).

Answer (score 2):

You problem is here:

```java
pairs.put((String)m[0], Double.parseDouble((String)m[1]));
```

The first for loop creates a string that ends with a `,`. For example `"foo:0.1,bar:0.2,"`.

Then, you split by `,`. So, the above example will return `["foo:0.1"; "bar:0.2"; ""]`. Note the empty string value, due to the last `,` of the string.

Finally, for each value, you split by `:`. It works for the first two values (i.e. `["foo"; "0.1"]` and `["bar"; "0.2"]`), but the last one will be a 1-value array, containing an empty string: `[""]`.

When trying to access the second value of the array (i.e. the index `1` since arrays are 0-based indexed), the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` get thrown.

---

Several solutions:

In the first loop, put a condition to add the `,` or not:

```java
myPairs += (i == 0 ? "" : ",") + (String)data[i][0] + ":" + String.valueOf(data[i][1]);
```

**OR** Just after your first loop, remove the last char of the string:

```java
myPairs = myPairs.substring(0, myPairs.length() - 1);
```

**OR** In the second loop, don't go until the last value, but only until the *n-1* one:

```java
for (int i=0; i<l.length - 1; i++)
```

**OR** even better, only if you don't need the string representation you're building in the first loop, replace all your code by:

```java
for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    pairs.put((String)data[i][0], Double.parseDouble((String)data[i][1])); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the first for-loop ends, you have all the pairs separated with ',' and an extra ',' in the end. So, l.length is the number of pairs plus one. Though, this shouldn't produce an error so far.

The problem is that when you split every pair on ':', the last element of `l` is equal to a blank string.
So the splitting produces an 1-element-array, containing a blank string. The error occures because you ask for `m[1]`.

Try not adding the ',' after the last element of the pairs, and the problem should be solved.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The last element in the split of `,`s is empty (because you say `+ ","` on the last iteration of the first loop), so skip the last element in the second loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.length-1; i++)
{
    m = l[i].split(":");
    pairs.put((String)m[0], Double.parseDouble((String)m[1]));             
}
```

Also note that if the supplied strings contains `:`s or `,`s, your algorithm would probably throw an exception too.

Note - A way better way (and to avoid the above) would just be to do it in the first loop, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    pairs.put((String)data[i][0], Double.parseDouble((String)data[i][1]));
}
```